# Can't access my locally hosted site

Tags: webserver, domain-name

I have successfully hosted a WAMP Webserver site locally on the pc of IP=`192.168.4.20`,  and given it the domain of `lsadcw.net`.

So whenever I write `lsadcw.net` in my browser URL area, the site shows up on the hosted machine. Now, the website can be accessed on my phone by writing `192.168.4.20`. But, I am unable to access it using "lsadcw.net". The phone model is Sony Xperia E3 and the PC is a Windows 7 self built machine.

Comment: is your phone configured to use a DNS server on your LAN, or is it using an ISP or Carrier DNS server? It probably depends on your DHCP server settings for your LAN.

Comment: Have you configured your domain's DNS settings to point to your public IP? Unless I'm reading wrong, that seems to be the issue. The reason it works locally is because you're forcing it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Insane said, the problem is your DNS.

The Windows machine knows its name is "lsadcw.net" because you advised it of that fact - but nothing has told your phone this.

In order to fix the problem you will need to tell your phone the IP address - and unfortunately this is not trivial.   There are 2 ways to do it - by editing the phones "hosts" file - which is probably not possible unless you have jailbroken/rooted it, or by changing the DNS.

Unfortunately changing the DNS requires either that you run your own nameserver and have it configured (eg on the router and have it provide DHCP - but most off-the-shelf routers can't do this), or by registerering the domain "lsadcw.net" with a registrar like Namecheap, and setting an A record to point to 192.168.4.20 - and while this will work, its not ideal as it will only work when you are on your LAN.

Comment: OH. I assumed he already registered the domain! Yes, OP, you must buy a domain in order to use it on the public internet :P

Comment: it is a local site, and want to access it locally using the lsadcw.net