# How to bind local ip with a domain name in wordpress?

Tags: apache-http-server, wordpress

I have installed lamp on debian8 and wordpress on /var/www/html/wp.
Now the /var/www/html was on the machine which ip is 192.168.1.100 on the family lan.

```
vim  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80>
    ServerName  mywp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wp
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Why my wordpress can't be visited when to input `mywp.com' in firefox?
How to create a domain name to use in my family lan?
And bind the domain name`mywp.com`  with 192.168.1.100?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access my locally hosted site](http://superuser.com/questions/978819/cant-access-my-locally-hosted-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a domain, you have to **buy** one, then point the DNS records to your public IP address.

If you want to use a domain **locally**, you must edit the **hosts** files for *each device* you want to be able to access the site.

### Editing Windows Hosts Files in Windows:

Add the following line into `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
192.168.1.100     mywp.com
```

### Pointing a domain

This heavily depends on the registrar you use, but you want to add an **A domain record** with the following settings:

```
Host: @
IP Address: your-public-IP
```

You can also add another **A Record** for your site to be accessible with `www.` infront:

```
Host: www
IP Address: your-public-IP
```

More info here: [How can I point my domain name to my home server's IP?](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1162/10/how-can-i-point-my-domain-name-to-my-home-servers-ip)